# Prove the following expression with induction

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics, summation, notation, induction

> Prove that:
>   $$
> 9+16+\dots+(n+2)^2 = \frac{n^3}{3}+\frac{5n^2}{2}+\frac{37n}{6} 
> $$with induction.

I managed to prove the base step but got stuck with the induction step.

Could anyone please help me with the induction step?

Comment: Just copy the induction proof for $1^2 + 2^2 + ... + n^2 = \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}$ and rewrite.

Comment: Will take a look at it, thank you for the link.

Comment: Cf. [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3554413/prove-with-induction)

Comment: But my answer is still okay, right!

Comment: @NeoPlato Yes. Thank you!

Comment: Any time man. I'm also practicing so thanks too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the inductive step all you do is show that if the formula is true for $n$ it is true for $n+1$. In this case, you show that taking the value for $n$ and adding  $n+1$ is the same as using $n+1$ as the input:

$\frac{n^3}{3}+\frac{5n^2}{2}+\frac{37n}{6}+((n+1)+2)^2=\frac{(n+1)^3}{3}+\frac{5(n+1)^2}{2}+\frac{37(n+1)}{6}$

$\frac{n^3}{3}+\frac{5n^2}{2}+\frac{37n}{6}+((n+1)+2)^2=\frac{n^3}{3}+\frac{5n^2}{2}+\frac{37n}{6}+n^2+6n+9$

$=\frac{n^3}{3}+n^2+n+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{5n^2}{2}+5n+\frac{5}{2}+\frac{37n}{6}+\frac{37}{6} \implies \text{Distribution of extra terms.}$

$=\frac{n^3+3n^2+3n+1}{3}+\frac{5n^2+10n+5}{2}+\frac{37n+37}{6}$

$=\frac{(n+1)^3}{3}+\frac{5(n+1)^2}{2}+\frac{37(n+1)}{6}$

So if it works for 1, it works for 2, 3 and so on, "which is the very thing it was required to show". $\implies$ Elements, Euclid